# C# IEnumerator implicit memory allocation

Tags: c#, delegates, dynamic-memory-allocation, ienumerator

I have an instance of a class that has a datastructure that stores IEnumerator (say a List) and every t milliseconds it calls MoveNext() on every enumerator.

I also have a "void Add(IEnumerator en) " method that adds the IEnumerator to the datastructure.

If I have an IEnumerator method of this form:

```
IEnumerator MyMethod()
{
     code();
     yield return something();
     code();
}
```

Does anything get allocated when I call

```
instance.Add(MyMethod())
```

?

Comment: Add is only supported when memory is internally allocated, otherwise enumerator simply does read only move forward operation, which collections like list implement

Comment: `MyMethod` returns an object that implements `IEnumerable`; that object has to get allocated at some point before it is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, yield return statement creates a statemachine under the hood, so when you call the method, you are not actually calling the method MyMethod, it is calling the state machine object.

You will get IEnumerator when you call something like :

```
Program p = new Program();
var enumerator = p.MyMethod();
```

If you put a break on the MyMethod, you will see the method is never been called, but rather the IEnumerator is been created through it.

Now if you call MoveNext to the enumerator, that will actually call the method.

So in your case the list will just hold enumerator, and the actual call is delayed when you actually retrieve the objects.

On terms of memory allocation, the state machine is actually allocated, but all the objects that are created inside MyMethod is still not allocated.